# Should I keep requiring dotenv npm module in the app.js source file before deploying to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, dotenv

I know that we must not commit the .env file to Heroku by adding the .env file to .gitignore but should I keep this line of code in the app.js source file?

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

Or should be delete this line before git pushing?

I have another related question. In order for the node app to work with Heroku, they make us add this to the app.js :

```
const port = process.env.PORT
```

How can it work without having required the dotenv module? Are they adding this requirement to the app.js file as part of the deployment process?

Comment: Yes, you should keep this line on app.js. You shouldn't commit .env file.

Comment: process.env.PORT is default variable avaiable inside heroku environment.

Comment: @Narayan Sharma Ok so you confirm that the require statement doesn't conflict with heroku environment? This is basically what I wanted to know by asking this question ;)

Comment: you have also the possibility to add your config var directly in the Heroku settings : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars